# Android: Layout always 2/3 screen

Tags: android, layout

I have many views which I'm adding in the scroll view (by `<include>` ). These layouts are like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I include those layouts into the `fragment` layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
        >
            <include layout="@layout/one"/>
            <include layout="@layout/two"/>
            <include layout="@layout/three"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How to make this 3 layouts take height always 2/3 of the screen. I want to have it always at 2/3 of the screen on each device. `layout_weight` doesn't work as intended.

Comment: why don't you programmatically get height of device and set to your desire view with 2/3 ratio .

Comment: @AdnanMaqbool thanks for comment but I would need to post another question how to do that, to be honest. Can you tell me the way?

Comment: check my updated answer . hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get width and height of screen in Mulitple way

```
public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}

public static int getScreenHeight() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}
```

**getScreenHeight()** will return total height

*You can use this height and set the params as follows:*

```
desired_height_params = getScreenHeight() *2/3

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    desired_height_params
);
linLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```